# Why does my variable determining an item in a list become out of range?

Tags: python, list, function

So, I'm working on a function that will take a data list, and make a new list with items that repeat over a given number removed. So far, I have this while loop in the function

```
def solution(data, n):
    timesRepeated = n
    lengthData = data.__len__()
    j = 0
    while (j <= lengthData):
        num = data[j]
        if (check(data, num, n)):
            print("Thisimes")
            data = (list(filter((num).__ne__, data)))
            j = 0
            lengthData = data.__len__()
        if (j == lengthData):
            break
        j += 1
```

The check() function just checks if num appears in the list more than n times and returns True if so. It's working as intended, I'm just missing something in the while loop

So, this is for the Google foobar test, so I don't want a solution to the function, but I just want to know why my j variable goes out of range of data. I keep getting this error: "IndexError: list index out of range" with this function run: solution([1, 2, 3], 0). If anyone could help an aspiring pythonista, it would be appreciated.

Edit: Thanks for the help, looking back on it, I realized my errors. Didn't know that I could just use <, thanks. Also, I just googled the 'data.**len**()'  because I was unfamiliar with list attributes, so I'll replace that. The second if, I'll remove. The intended output would be nothing, since all of the items occur more than 0. I also realized that the 'num = data[j]' wouldn't be accurate since the length changes every iteration. Thanks for the feedback, I'll make those changes and answer this if it works

Comment: Could you tell us what the intended output is?

Comment: `<=` should be `<`. List indexes go from 0 to length-1

Comment: There's no need for the `if`, since `while` will stop when you get to the end.

Comment: Why do you write `data.__len__()` instead of `len(data)`?

Comment: Consider `data = [i for i in data if i != num]`.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the suggestion. Can you explain how that works exactly? I've seen suggestions like that when googling it, but I wasn't sure exactly how the fors and ifs in a list work.

Comment: @TimRoberts Google "python list comprehension"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j <= lengthData` will let `j` reach a value beyond the last index in `data` which is `lengthData-1` because Python list indexes are zero based.

Use `while j < lengthData:` instead

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I figured out why the num variable kept going out of range. Since I would be removing items, the order of those items would change. Therefore, j would become higher the more iterations the while loop would run, so with the data being [1,2,3] and the n being 0, l would always be higher than 0 which would be the end result of the while loop. Thanks for all the help and suggestions. My work is not done yet, but at least this problem is. Have a good day everyone

Edit: Nevermind, Barmar and Alain T had it right, it was due to the <= not being <. Thanks again